# Is the list $(0, 1, 2, \cdots), (1, 2, 3, \cdots), (2, 3, 4, \cdots), \cdots$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{(x_1, x_2, \cdots) | x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $(0, 1, 2, \cdots), (1, 2, 3, \cdots), (2, 3, 4, \cdots), \cdots$ be elements of $\{(x_1, x_2, \cdots) | x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$

I guess the list $(0, 1, 2, \cdots), (1, 2, 3, \cdots), (2, 3, 4, \cdots), \cdots$ is linearly independent but I cannot prove that.

Is the list $(0, 1, 2, \cdots), (1, 2, 3, \cdots), (2, 3, 4, \cdots), \cdots$ linearly independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_1= (0,1,2,...), v_2 = (1,2,3,...)$ and $v_3 = (2,3,4,...)$. Observe that $v_3 - v_2 = (1,1,1,...)$, which leads to $v_1 = v_2 - (v_3 - v_2)$. So, they are not linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you very much, curlycharcoal.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not. Taking the first $3$ vectors you have:
\begin{equation}
- (0,1,2,3,\cdots) + 2\cdot (1,2,3,\cdots) - (2,3,4,\cdots) = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you very much, Menezio.